# To take value from xml file and insert it to url ( GET request)

Tags: xml, perl, url, xml-parsing

I need to extract a value from an XML document and add it to a URL.

When I make a GET request with all devices for my web service I get this XML data

#### FILE.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:searchResult total="3" xmlns:ns2="ers.ise.cisco.com">
    <resource name="TEST_1" id="1" description="example nd">
      <link type="application/xml" href="https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/1" rel="self"/>
    </resource>
    <resource name="TEST_2" id="2>
      <link type="application/xml" href="https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/2" rel="self"/>
    </resource>
    <resource name="TEST_3" id="3" description="example nd">
      <link type="application/xml" href="https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/3" rel="self"/>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</ns2:searchResult>
```

My result contains just `Name` and `ID` but I need the devices' IP addresses too, and to get it I should make a GET request passing the ID in the URL

For example: `https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/1`

I did not find an API to get more information for all devices.

Does anyone know how can I loop my IDs? Can I insert the value into my URL?

#### My current code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;
use REST::Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Request;

my $xml1 = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('FILE.xml');

foreach my $id ($xml1->root->att('id'))
# .........
# I don't know what I should make here


#Create a user agent object
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts=> {
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE(),
    verify_hostname => 0,
});

#Create a request
my $uri = 'https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice'; # I need to insert my ID into this URL
my $header = HTTP::Headers->new;
$header->Header(Accept => 'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $uri, $header);


$req->authorization_basic("user", "password");

# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ( $res->is_success ) {
    print $res->content;
} 
else {
    print $res->status_line, "n";
}
```

After that, I need to save all my devices into one XML file.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you need is in the `href` attribute of the `link` element within each resource. Just pick up the value of that attribute and use it directly